# How to interpret this part of an integration? (Areas and volumes)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This semester I've learnt how to calculate areas and volumes by using double and triple integrations, the procedure was easy and kind of easy, but there was thing that I never could really understand it at 100%, it's more of a nitpick to be honest.

To better elaborate my problem I'll work with rectangles and cuboids. Sorry for the bad drawing.

[image]

The formula to calculate the area of this rectangle is

$\iint_V dx\,dy$

$ V = \{ 0 \le x  \le 4  \land 0 \le y\le2  \}$

or

$\int_W 2dx$

$ W = \{ 0 \le x  \le 4 \} $

In my opinion the second one is easier to explain. Using the "ray" analogy, that for each $x$ value there's a ray of "height" 2 that's shoot and the sum of all of them is the area.

Here comes the problem,

Since 
$\iint_V dx\,dy = \iint_V 1 * dx\,dy $

What does the 1 mean in this context?

The closest thing i could come up with is that it is the height of a rectangular cuboid and since it's 1, the area of the base is equal to the volume. Is  this assertion correct?

[image]

Comment: The trouble with adding up "rays" of length $2$ is that by the time you add up $5$ of them, you've already exceeded the area of the rectangle, and you still have infinitely many to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly right. The same idea works in higher dimensions, too.

Say we wanted to calculate the volume of the unit cube (trivial, I know, but it's just an example). We can express that as

$$\iiint_R\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=\iiint_R1\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z,$$

where $R=\{(x,y,z)\mid0\le x,y,z\le1\}$, which is, essentially, describing a four-dimensional figure with a length of $1$ in some fourth spatial dimension (whatever that might actually be).

Answer (score 0):

It means the area of each infinitesimal element (rectangle) of dimensions $dx$ and $dy$ is $dx$ times $dy$ i.e. $= dxdy = 1*dxdy$. We take as units, a square formed by unit 1 side has area of 1 in corresponding area units.